# How to override Devise confirmation instructions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise and trying to create a new user(customer) programmatically and send the customer his password by email. I have created a custom mailer and have overridden the confirmation_instructions method. This code below works fine. After I programmatically create the customer, the customer is sent an email with the custom header "Bar" and a confirmation link is sent.

```
class CustomMailer < Devise::Mailer   
    helper :application # gives access to all helpers defined within `application_helper`.
    include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers # Optional. eg. `confirmation_url`

    def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
        headers["Custom-header"] = "Bar"          
    super
  end
end
```

But I need to also send a password, so I tried this:

```
class CustomMailer < Devise::Mailer   
    helper :application # gives access to all helpers defined within `application_helper`.
    include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers # Optional. eg. `confirmation_url`

    def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
        headers["Custom-header"] = "Bar"
        @password = opts[:password]
        super
    end
end
```

And I manually call the email method like this from my controller:

```
@customer_instance = Customer.new({ :email => customer_params[:email], :password => generated_password, :password_confirmation => generated_password, :first_name => customer_params[:first_name], :last_name => customer_params[:last_name] })
@customer_instance.skip_confirmation!
@customer_instance.save

CustomMailer.confirmation_instructions(@customer_instance, @customer_instance.confirmation_token, {password: generated_password}).deliver
```

The password gets sent fine, but the confirmation token does not get sent. How can I use Devise to create a confirmation token to pass in here? Or is there a different way of doing it where I don't need to pass the token in manually?

Answer (score 6):

Assigning a temporary password is dangerous because the user will most likely be too lazy to change it.  Also, the email could be intercepted by someone else who beats the legitimate user to changing the password.  Now the account is in someone else's controler.

Instead, don't assign any password when you create the account.  Use Devise's `:confirmable` module:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :confirmable, etc...
```

When `confirmable` is used, as soon as the record is saved, devise will automatically send an email to the user with a link to click on to confirm the account.  When the click on that link, devise will update the DB to mark the record as confirm, and then redirect them to the root_path of your Rails project.

This behavior is defined in the method [after_confirmation_path_for](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb#L40), so override that method in your ApplicationController and have it return the url for a page where they are forced to set their password (such as `edit_user_path(current_user)` if your devise model is `User`).

In addition, add a before_filter to your ApplicationController so that they are forced to reset their password before continuing.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  private 
    before_filter :force_user_to_set_password
    def force_user_to_set_password
      redirect_to edit_user_path(current_user), :notice => "First, create a password" if user_signed_in? && current_user.encrypted_password.blank?
    end

    def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
      __send__("edit_#{resource_name}_path", resource)
    end
end
```

And, of course, prevent them from getting stuck in redirect loops:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  private
    skip_before_filter :force_user_to_set_password, :only => [:edit, :update]
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve this by accessing the password in the view by doing this:

```
<%= @resource.password %>
```

This means there isn't a need to call the mailer method manually and pass in the password.

Comment: You should never be exposing their password in plaintext anyway.  That's why it wasn't in devise's mailer templates to begin with.  What are you really trying to do?  Think about what your goal is and find another way to do it that doesn't involve putting the password in plaintext.

Comment: Also, it's probably safer to use `resource` instead of `@resource`.

Comment: I am trying to let a user sign up by only providing an email address. I send them a temporary password so they can confirm their account with it. They can change their password afterwords if they want. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: There is absolutely a better way to do this.  I will post it as an aswer.